# VHDL code error 211 modelsim shifter

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
--use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity shifter is
port(inputt:in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      shiftextent:in integer ;
   outt :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0));
end shifter;


architecture shifter_art of shifter is

begin

g1: for b in 0 to 7 generate
  outt(b+shiftextent)<= inputt(b);
  end generate;
g2: for c in shiftextent to 15 generate
outt(c)<='0';
end generate;
g3: for d in 0 to shiftextent generate
outt(d)<='0';
end generate;

end shifter_art;
```

Hey Guys, i am trying to make a shifter as a part of an arithmetic multiplier.
I'm using modelsim for compilation and its crashing and giving me error 211. 
Can you help me figure out if there is something wrong with this code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure. There would normally be a message and perhaps a line number as well as the number 211. Those would identify the cause of the error and the place it occurred.

Comment: The `shiftextent` is a input signal/port, but used in the `g2: for c in shiftextent to 15 generate`, but generate needs static range, so at least that is wrong.  Beware, you are writing hardware, not software.

Comment: Thanks guys , and Brian it just exited no cause of error displayed.